# List first depth dirs by Amazon s3 client

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I uploaded some folders to my s3 bucket, for example:

```
s3cmd  sync myfirstdir  s3://my-bucket/myfirstdir/
s3cmd  sync myseconddir  s3://my-bucket/myseconddir/
s3cmd  sync mythirddir  s3://my-bucket/mythirddir/
```

these dirs(myfirstdir, myseconddir, mythrids) also include sub dirs and also plain files

How can I list these dirs by amazon s3 client, but not subdirs. What I want is just the return of
`s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/`, it just list the first depth files or dirs, but not recursively

```
myfirstdir
myseconddir
mythirddir
```

I tried following code, but it returned each of files and dirs recursively

```
            ObjectListing objects = conn.listObjects(bucket.getName());
            do {
                for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {

                    System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey());
                }
                objects = conn.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
            } while (objects.isTruncated());
```

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`. It would appear that `s3cmd` hasn't had a [release](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/releases) for 1.5 years.

Answer (score 1):

Python equivalent:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Delimiter='/')

for prefix in response['CommonPrefixes']:
    print(prefix['Prefix'])
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't have folders as "physical objects". There is a bucket and you put files in there.

Each file has an associated Path.

Now its true that if the Path has slash ("/") in its name it will shown in UI tools as a folder, but it doesn't work like a "usual" filesystem.

In the official documentation ou can find an[overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html) of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListObjectsV2Result result = conn.listObjectsV2(new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucket.getName()).withDelimiter("/"));
for (String prefix : result.getCommonPrefixes()) {
    System.out.println(prefix);
}
```

I translate part of the code of this page: https://github.com/koblas/s3-cli/blob/master/cmd_ls.go to Java, so it can show only first level dirs under the bucket